# SVN from linux to windows

Tags: linux, windows, svn

We're running a local development machine (windows) with svn.
Our production servers (linux) are on another location so we cannot connect from the production servers to the local development server to do a svn checkout.

I know it's possible.
Does anybody know how to connect from the linux (external production) to the windows (local development) server to do some svn tasks?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any network connectivity at all?  If not, sneakernet.

Answer (score 0):

You could try SSH port forwarding from the local machines or a VPN. Or use port-forwarding to the development server from your external router.

Or you can clone the svn server to another one machine that can be accessed from the production servers.

Or using gitsvn you can transfer the repo from the svn and then push the changes to the server...